# What is the function which can replace onReceive()?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have some code;

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask.. {

 /*----- some code
  */
protected Void doInBackground(){

    process1;

    process2;

    ....

    process10;


      }
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

     if(action==abc){

           myAsyncTask=new MyAsyncTask();

           myAsyncTask.excute(context);

     }

 }
```

**I see that in the results: some time "process10" was not implemented.**

As i know:

- onReceive () can not handle long works then it can kill any process contain anytime.
- Avoid handling the code too long in onReceive ().
- No handle asynchronous callback wait ... in Receiver (as shown Dialog particular, the connection service ...)

so , issue was happen.but i have not solution to fix it yet.

I would like get some help from all to resolve my issue

please help me !
thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IntentService for this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

```
package com.example.myapp;

public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

   public MyIntentService() {
      super("MyIntentService");
   }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         process1;
         process2;

         ....

         process10;
    }
}
```

Register this service in your Manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application ... >
        <service android:name="com.example.myapp.MyIntentService" />
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Finally start the IntentService in your onReceive()-method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    if(action.equals(abc)){
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class)
       context.startService(intent)
    }
}
```